# Retrieving most recent commit revision number from a github project

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How do you retrieve the revision number for the most recent commit of a github project?

The [APIv3 docs](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) are a little vague, and only provide a partially URL that doesn't seem to work.

e.g. Does /repos/:user/:repo/commits correspond to https://www.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/commits? OR something else like https://www.github.com/api/v2/json/repos/:user/:repo/commits? Neither work for any combination of user and repo.

Comment: Git does not have a concept of "revision number".  Are you looking for the SHA1 object name of the commit instead?  Or for the output of `git describe`?  Or for yet another thing?

Comment: Yes...whatever piece of "text" uniquely identifies the latest commit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In git, you can only ask for the current commit on some given branch.  Here's an example:

```bsh
$ wget -q -O - https://api.github.com/repos/smarnach/pyexiftool/git/refs/heads/master 
{
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/smarnach/pyexiftool/git/refs/heads/master",
  "object": {
    "type": "commit",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/smarnach/pyexiftool/git/commits/7be4b9bb680521369f2ae3310b1f6de5d14d1f8b",
    "sha": "7be4b9bb680521369f2ae3310b1f6de5d14d1f8b"
  }
}
```